# Jquery - Slider for pdf documents

Tags: jquery, pdf, slider

Is it possible to use a slider for a pdf document with multiple pages so that it slides through the pdf like a magazine?

And if so, where could I find information about such a slider?

Comment: How do you do the rendering of the pdf document ? I mean with flash plugin or a jquery plugin for example.

Comment: @CharlesJourdan I would like it to be Jquery

Comment: http://pdfobject.com/ I found this project to convert pdf into html.